# Appending with StringBuilder

Tags: android, checkbox, stringbuilder

I have 5 checkboxes and I have to select multiple checkboxes.

I made a code like this to check check box is checked:

```
sports=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sports_btn);
sports.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (sports.isChecked() == true)
        list.add("4");
    }
});
```

I am adding a value to an array list:

```
list ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and I am retrieving the value as string like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int  i =0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    for (String str: list)
    {  
        sb.append(str.toString());
        sb.append(",");
    }

}
String sel_cat = sb;
```

I am getting the string but if two values are selected it is coming like 2,3,
How to remove that last comma? I don't want the last comma the string has to be like 2,3.

Comment: imho you are always better off using code already written and tested then rolling your own hence my recommendation of using the opensource apache string util library

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1)
```

**Or in your code, use**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int  i =0;i<list.size();i++)
{
    String prefix = "";
    for (String str : list)
    { 
        sb.append(prefix);
        prefix = ",";
        sb.append(str);  
    }
}

String sel_cat = sb;
```

Comment: Cancelled my ofvote for the reason that I don't understand why `str.toString()` is used in `append()` call. Isn't that already a `String` ? Also, will the last line; `String sel_cat = sb;` compile ?

Answer (score 5):

You can put the condition to check:

```
for (String str : list)
{
   sb.append(str.toString());
   if (i!=list.size()-1)
   {
     sb.append(",");
   }
}
```

Comment: That was my first move too, but it requires a condition in each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

You can put your string array in condition:

```
String list[]=new String[]{"A","C","D","F"};

public String print(String arr[]){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String prefix = "";
    for (String str : arr)
    { 
        sb.append(prefix);
        prefix = ",";
        sb.append(str);  
    }

    System.out.println("WithCommas"+sb);
    return sb;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use deleteCharAt:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int  i =0;i<list.size();i++)
{
    for (String str : list)
    {  
        sb.append(str); // str is already a String, no need for toString()
        sb.append(",");
    }
}
if (sb.length() > 0) {
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
}
String sel_cat=sb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to look at [`StringUtils#join(Object\[\], String, int, int)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29):

there is a join method which can take an array and put it together with a delimeter...

ex:

```
 StringUtils.join([null, "", "a"], ',')   // creates... ",,a"
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't just dump code as your answer, explain what you are doing so people can understand how to solve the problem. Thanks.