# Android: Can not print file content properly

Tags: java, android, println

I m trying to print the content of a file that is stored inside the internal storage of my app, but something strange happens.

This is the function:

```
   public void print() throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fin = fileContext.getApplicationContext().openFileInput("myfile");
    System.out.println("File Found");
    int c;
    String temp = "";
    while ((c = fin.read()) != -1) {
        temp = temp + Character.toString((char) c);
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
    System.out.println("Please Print Something To Test");
    fin.close();
```

When I run the application the System.out inside the while cicle works perfectly.. But the `Systm.out.println(temp)` outside the while cicle is not called at all.
The strangest thing is that the `System.out.println("Please Print Something To Test");` is called properly. 
Now what can be the problem, am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: This is not A dublicate.. i have read all other threads and this is a particular case that nobody had

Comment: `temp` is "", that's why it doesn't show. Btw you need to close resources in a finally block because if an exception is thrown, `fin` will never be closed.

Comment: I do not feel the marked duplicate answers this question at all. Merely a side issue. @m0skit0 comment better answers it. Ive flagged for re-open

Comment: @m0skit0 but the temp is filled inside the while cicle.. Then at the end it should be filled with the full string..

Comment: Then it is clear it either doesn't enter the loop at all or all the characters are not printable. You can put a breakpoint and check the actual values.

Comment: Try using `StringBuilder` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167088/appending-with-stringbuilder  . Also, if you are trying to read the whole file in? There are much faster, easier ways.

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes it enter inside the loop for sure..

Comment: @Doomsknight I'll try StringBulilder I will let you know

Comment: Did you debug it? I've been sure about a lot of things until I debugged.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read from file by using this way:

```
File file = new File("myfile");
FileInputStream fis = null;

try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    int content;
    while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
        // convert to char and display it
        System.out.print((char) content);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (fis != null)
            fis.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: In this way I can not solve my problem.. I would like to print the final string without print a bunch of string inside the while cicle..

Comment: Hmm. just append to an arraylist or string array instead of print every character. And then print it outside the loop. I think it's easy for you  :)