# I get null with each output. like "nullid:1 nullName:sufyan nullFatherName"

Tags: java, android

I get null with each output. like the following is the class :

```
@override
 public void onResponse(String response) {


                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                      
      for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++){

                                JSONObject jsonObject = 
jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);



                                String id  = jsonObject.getString("id");

                                String name  = jsonObject.getString("name");

                                String fathername  = 
jsonObject.getString("fathername");

                                String no  = jsonObject.getString("no");

                                jsonResponseId += "Id: " + id + "\n\n";

                                jsonResponseName += "Name: " + name + "\n\n";

                                jsonResponseFather += "FatherName: " + 
fathername + "\n\n";

                                jsonResponseNumber += "Number: " + no + "\n\n";

                                idText.setText(jsonResponseId);

                                nameText.setText(jsonResponseName);

                                fatherNameText.setText(jsonResponseFather);

                                numberText.setText(jsonResponseNumber);

                            }

}
}
```

Comment: can your provide you json Response

Comment: Please provide your Json Object, without which we cannot help

Comment: @SufyanShabbir I want to suggest you to use **[StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167088/appending-with-stringbuilder)** at the place of string concatination

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the variables jsonResponseId etc so that they are not null, **but**

A simpler solution would be to do away these variables and just set them like

```
idText.setText("Id: " + id + "\n\n");
```

Answer (score -1):

You should replace `+=` by `==`

Because `+=` often use for numeric. You should use `append` for string